# SQL Server compressed backup firstly huge?

Tags: sql-server, backup

Is this a default/normal behavior? When we start a backup it create a file of 316gb and only after backup finishing it shrink to 131gb. Don't make sense because in this case we need a disk of 316gb or more to start the backup, even if it is compressed to 131gb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. SQL Server doesn't know how large the file with end up to, and for performance reasons it pre-allocates a file size based on a guestimate. And in the end reduces the file size. In your case, it was apparently larger than it ended up needing.

Fortunately, you can change this behavior using trace flag 3042, which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

The tests I've seen suggests an increased backup time of about 5%, but those were for smaller databases.

Comment: Thanks for answer and reference! The performance penalty is only for backup processes, right? is safe enable it globally and leave this setting always enabled? DBCC TRACEON (3042,-1)

Comment: Yes the penalty is only for backup. And the trace flag is documented, meaning it is also supported.